# Help with Multi-variable Calculus and Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, lagrange-multiplier

This question is not part of my course (I do Economics) or probably at my capabilities as of yet. But I wish to have a greater understanding of 3D geometry (I believe that is the area). I received this question from a bonus question from a summer exam paper and am seeking help with it. So without further ado..

minimum value for $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ where $x, y, z$ are real numbers such that  $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = 1$

Thank you for any help!

P.S.
Is my constraint $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$??

P.S.S. 
Nevermind

P.S.S.S. 
So after finding critical points I plugged them back into the function, I got roughly 0.11791 as my lowest value, unsure if this is correct.

Comment: I would read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: The standard method for minimizing functions of several variables subject to constraints is Lagrange multipliers. If you google that there will be a good amount of reading /viewing material aimed at students learning multivariable calculus.

Comment: Thank you! I will probably have to read a lot as this method isn't familiar with me. I'm new to this and would like to show appreciation for your comments! is there any up-vote system?

Comment: Is there multiple minimum points for z and y? If so which do I choose?